# ESP 32 changing frequency instead of duty cycle

Tags: pwm, esp32, frequency

Using this code on an esp32 allow to vary duty cycle of the PWM with a fixed 5000Hz frequency and is working fine.

My question is how to vary frequency and keep duty cycle on a fixed value?

```cpp
// the number of the LED pin
const int ledPin = 16;  // 16 corresponds to GPIO16

// setting PWM properties
const int freq = 5000;
const int ledChannel = 0;
const int resolution = 8;

void setup(){
  // configure LED PWM functionalitites
  ledcSetup(ledChannel, freq, resolution);

  // attach the channel to the GPIO to be controlled
  ledcAttachPin(ledPin, ledChannel);
}

void loop(){
  // increase the LED brightness
  for(int dutyCycle = 0; dutyCycle <= 255; dutyCycle++){   
    // changing the LED brightness with PWM
    ledcWrite(ledChannel, dutyCycle);
    delay(15);
  }

  // decrease the LED brightness
  for(int dutyCycle = 255; dutyCycle >= 0; dutyCycle--){
    // changing the LED brightness with PWM
    ledcWrite(ledChannel, dutyCycle);   
    delay(15);
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: const int freq = 5000; - this is the frequency

Comment: Hm. Right, sorry

Comment: Use `ledcWriteTone` ?

Comment: Why remove points on the question? changing the frequency will be helpful if you are working with a stepper motor for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the pwm frequency during runtime there is a function `ledc_set_freq()` for this purpose. I'm not sure if your duty cycle will remain valid, but I guess it does as long as the resolution does not change. You will have to try that on your own and eventually implement a compensation.

Comment: I tried using ledc_set_freq but the issue is that if do it very quickly then is not set it anymore. If I do this on a normal arduino using pwm library i can change pin frequency each 50ms and is fine.